# Why query on MYSQL is slow as compared to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two database e.g. MYSQL and MariaDb.
I create identical tables and insert same data. When I run same query on it, the execution time of query in MYSQL is too much. Can anyone tell what is the reason of this even in mysql, it scan less rows according to the execution plan.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    t.AccountCode AS Code,
    t.AccountDescription AS Description,
    t.Payment AS Total,
    COALESCE(SUM(l.DebitAmount - l.CreditAmount), 0.0) AS Balance
FROM
    Ledgers AS l
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        m.AccountCode,
        m.AccountDescription,
        COALESCE(SUM(l0.CreditAmount), 0.0) AS Payment
    FROM
        Ledgers AS l0
    INNER JOIN Masters AS m ON (l0.AccountCode = m.AccountCode)
        AND ((l0.CompanyCode = m.BranchCode) OR (l0.CompanyCode IS NULL AND m.BranchCode IS NULL))
    WHERE
        (l0.CreationDate >= '2022-07-01' AND l0.CreationDate < '2022-07-02')
        AND (l0.CompanyCode = '029')
        AND (l0.Type IN ('CRV', 'BRV') AND l0.CreditAmount > 0.0)
    GROUP BY
        m.AccountCode, m.AccountDescription
) AS t ON l.AccountCode = t.AccountCode
WHERE
    (l.CreationDate >= '2022-07-01' AND l.CreationDate < '2022-07-02')
    AND (l.TransactionYear = '2022-2023')
    AND (l.CompanyCode = '029')
GROUP BY
    t.AccountCode, t.AccountDescription, t.Payment
ORDER BY
    t.AccountCode;
```

MariaDB Execution Plan (Query took 7.3797 seconds.)
[image: MariaDB Execution Plan (Query took 7.3797 seconds.)]

MYSQL Execution Plan (Query took 84.6042 seconds.)
[image]

Comment: You're sure the schemas are the same?  MySQL shows fewer indexes.

Comment: Yes both schemas are same.

Comment: It could be servers are different (or have different amount of RAM), it could be fifferent configuration of systems (maybe MariaDB it configured to use (8GB of RAM and Mysql is configured to use 1 Gb of RAM), and so on. Can be hundreds of things

Comment: How did you ensure that both systems are the same from the data. Just backing up one system and then importing it into the new one is not enough. With the new system, all rows are directly behind each other and there are no extinguishers. MySQL never gives!! return the free memory to the system,..... Check whether the binary files are about the same size

Comment: It is also unclear what vwrsion of mysql and mariadb are used. Mariadb seems to have created an index on the derived table, while mysql did not. This feature was added in mysql v5.6.3. If the mysql version is earlier than that, it may explain the difference in speed.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `select version();` and `show create table Ledger` and `show create table Masters`, for both databases.

Answer (score 0):

As visible from the execution plan, mariadb selects better indexes on all stages even when joining with subquery, while mysql (which version?) selects plan differently.

The difference is in handling table statistics to optimize your execution plan before starting data access. The field is large, but fun guaranteed. See for yourself: [MariaDB query optimizations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/query-optimizations/) vs [MySQL query optimizations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-optimization.html).

For this specific query you can:

- start by adding [STRAIGHT_JOIN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/optimizer-hints/#straight_join) after your SELECT keyword, if that doesn't help, then
- provide correct indexes manually via [FORCE INDEX()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/force-index/) hints after table names.

If you have a single query to execute, this can do the job. If you are selecting a DB for your product, do yourself a favor, check the differences of both engines. Because while being client compatible, their internals differ a lot these days.